# Can bytes(pdf) be opened from an ajax call

Tags: ajax, pdf, arrays, extjs4.1

My controller returns a pdf file using an ajax call. It's clear that using

`window.open(response.reponseText)`

is obviously not gonna help on success return

It'd be helpful if my controller that spits out the pdf file didn't take a List of object as a parameter. That's why I have to use an ajax call to call the controller. I can't use an iFrame for this exact reason as well. I found that using ajax I could send a json object. I can't do this using iframe.

Is there a way to open the returned file or even pop up a message box to download the file.

Comment: 1. No you cant use ajax for binary stream.   2. Parameters you send to the server side controller are preprocessed to provide input as objects. There is no difference between ajax get request and a src URL of IFrame with url encoded parameters as far as your controller is concerned.

Comment: Thanks dbrin... Will approach another route